# Why on printing I get value of null from API call in Loop

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, binance, cryptocurrency

COIN LIST is an array of crypto coins(["BTCUSDT",...]). I try to get the price using getPriceAction and RSI from getRSI and these two functions are working when I try to console DATA. But when I try to print the response after the completion of the loop. It prints the empty array and the length is 0 of this array. I want to store the DATA object (consisting of SYMBOL, closing price and RSI) as an element in the response array

```
 import { COIN_LIST } from "./COIN_LIST.js";
    import { getPriceAction } from "./PRICE_ACTION.js";
    import { getRSI } from "./RSI.js";

async function main() {
  try {
    let response = await [];
    await COIN_LIST.forEach((element, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let data = { symbol: element };
        getPriceAction(element, "4h").then((res) => {
          data.closingPrice = res;
          getRSI(res).then((res) => {
            data.RSI = res.reverse();
            data.closingPrice = data.closingPrice.reverse();
            response.push(data);
            console.log(data)
          });
        });
      }, i * 1000);
    });
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: `await COIN_LIST.forEach` ... what makes you think `forEach` returns a Promise? Array forEach returns `undefined` - always - also ... `let response = await [];` ... huh? an Array is an Array, not a Promise - [await documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) - I think you need to read how async/await works

Comment: Is the COIN_LIST a Promise<Array>? If so, then you need to use `(await COIN_LIST).forEach(...)`  Also, what do you mean by `let response = await []`? The array is not a promise in this line, so you should not use await in this line.

Comment: @Bravo where do u think there is a problem

Comment: @Tanay COIN_LIST is a pre-defined array consisting of coins

Comment: @BasitQayoom you should not use await on COIN_LIST if it is a pre defined array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use async/await properly for your code, then use async/await, don't use `.then`/`.catch` as well

Some notable changes

there is no setTimeout of increasing seconds ... just waiting 1 second after one result before getting the next - far cleaner, and if one request happens to take a lot longer, you won't end up with two requests at once (which may be an issue if the API is rate limited)

no `.then` ... use `async`/`await` OR `.then`/`.catch` - very rare to need both in the one function

don't use forEach with `async`/`await` ... it never does what you want, and creating an array of Promises inside a `.forEach` is extremely naive, you may as well use `.map` instead! then you can `await Promise.all(xxx.map(.....))` - but that's useful for concurrent requests, not so much for serial requests like your code does

```
import { COIN_LIST } from "./COIN_LIST.js";
import { getPriceAction } from "./PRICE_ACTION.js";
import { getRSI } from "./RSI.js";

async function main() {
    try {
        const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        let response = []; //---> don't need that `await`
        for (let element of COIN_LIST) {
            let data = { symbol: element };
            data.closingPrice = await getPriceAction(element, "4h");
            const res = await getRSI(data.closingPrice);
            data.RSI = res.reverse();
            data.closingPrice = data.closingPrice.reverse();
            response.push(data);
            console.log(data);
            await wait(1000);
        }
        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
main();
```

the `await wait(1000)` could be tweaked depending on the rate limiting of the API ... if the rate limit applies to when the request is made, you could make a function that is smart about the delay between requests.

The code this way assumes the rate limit is based on the period between previous response to next request.

Comment: can I use await keyword for console.log(response) outside try block

Comment: @BasitQayoom - TL;DR ... no need to use await for any part of `console.log(response);` as there are no promises involved at all .... the long version: why would you `await console.log`? you still don't get what async/await is ... it's syntax sugar for Promise ... you only "need" to await a Promise, and only if you need to get its value at that point in the code - console.log **anywhere** after where it is shown in that code (but WITHIN that async function) will  log correctly

Comment: @BasitQayoom - I'm guessing that you have an issue trying to use the `response` **outside** of `function main` ... but this answer addresses the code you posted, not the code you have

Answer (score -1):

After the completion of the loop, the promises didn't get resolved yet, that's why it print an empty array.
One way to achieve what you need is using `await for(...)`, or wait for all promises to be resolved, and then print the results.

```
import { COIN_LIST } from "./COIN_LIST.js";
import { getPriceAction } from "./PRICE_ACTION.js";
import { getRSI } from "./RSI.js";

async function main() {
  try {
    let response = []; //---> don't need that `await`
    const promises = []; //---> array of promises
    COIN_LIST.forEach((element, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let data = { symbol: element };
        const promise = getPriceAction(element, "4h").then((res) => {
          data.closingPrice = res;
          getRSI(res).then((res) => {
            data.RSI = res.reverse();
            data.closingPrice = data.closingPrice.reverse();
            response.push(data);
            console.log(data)
          });
        });
        promises.push(promise) //---> save the reference to a promise
      }, i * 1000);
    });
    await Promise.all(promises) //---> await for all promises to be resolved, then print the result
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: why not use `.map` if you want an array of Promises for Promise.all? That would make far more sense

Comment: @Bravo My intention was strictly to answer the question _Why on printing I get value of null from API call in Loop_ instead of teaching how to use promises. I wouldn't implement it in that way.